# Initializing pthread mutexes

Tags: c++, c

According to the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html) a mutex can be initialized in two ways:

Using the init function:

```
pthread_mutex_t theMutex;
pthread_mutex_init(&theMutex, NULL);
```

Using an initializer macro:

```
pthread_mutex_t result = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

About the latter the documentation says:

> In cases where default mutex attributes are appropriate, the macro PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER can be used to initialize mutexes that are statically allocated. The effect shall be equivalent to dynamic initialization by a call to pthread_mutex_init() with parameter attr specified as NULL, except that no error checks are performed.

Does this mean that it may only be used for static variables and not for local variables?

#### C++ Specific

I wanted to use the following "factory function":

```
static pthread_mutex_t GetFastNativeMutex()
{
    static pthread_mutex_t result = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    return result;
}
```

Because it would allow me to initialize mutexes in a C++ initializer list as follows:

```
MyClass() : myMutex(GetFastNativeMutex()) {}
```

Is this valid? (Btw in practice it works. Valgrind also doesn't complain.)

#### Update

If I understood the documentation correctly then this should be ok:

```
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_mutex_t m0 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t m1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t m2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

However, when looking at the preprocessor output (using `gcc -E main.cpp`) I see the following:

```
static pthread_mutex_t m0 = {0x32AAABA7, {0}};
static pthread_mutex_t m1 = {0x32AAABA7, {0}};
static pthread_mutex_t m2 = {0x32AAABA7, {0}};
```

It turns out that three times the same mutex was created. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How about switching to Boost.Thread mutexes that merely wrap pthreads on POSIX platforms? You get portability for free, and they are going to be standard in C++0x.

Comment: @ybungalobill I'm familiar with the Boost.Thread library, but for this particular project I don't have the choice.

Comment: Probably not and if it works its probably not doing what you expect. Remember this is a C interface.

Comment: What do you mean by the same mutex is created? There are three mutexes that are intialized to the same value. This is what the initializer macro is for. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Re "It turns out that three times the same mutex was created. What am I doing wrong here?"

You are doing nothing wrong here. The same mutex was not created three times. It looks like you are interpreting that 0x32AAABA7 as an address. It isn't. It is essentially an enum value, but with a Hamming code protection to (a) make it safe and (b) make it obscure. You have three distinct mutexes here.

Answer (score 9):

Standard does not allow to copy mutexes by value or return them by value. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html, the paragraph that explicitly talks about this, saying "IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 does not define assignment or equality for this type [pthread_mutex_t]"

The closest relative of pthread_mutex, WIN32 CriticalSection, is absolutely not copyable and not returnable by value. So your API will be very nonportable anyway.

I recommend against copying(returning) mutex by value even you can test it and it works.

Note that initializing a mutex is different from copying already initialized mutex.

Comment: After a bit of looking around I found this about `pthread_mutex_t` in the specs: "All of the types shall be defined as arithmetic types of an appropriate length, with the following exceptions" (where it is an exception) and "There are no defined comparison or assignment operators for the following types". Given that, I'm pretty sure that there is no guarantee that a copy of a mutex is meaningful.

Comment: @Luc thanks, I found the text about it in the posix standard itself (opengroup.org).

Answer (score 4):

Just because you can do it, doesn't mean you should.

The documentation clearly specifies that you use `pthread_mutex_init` at runtime and the other macro for statically allocated mutexes, I don't see any reason for not doing so.

Comment: @David Wrong or not, this kind of "hacking" up solutions to squeeze out a few cycles causes bugs down the road. The idea is that the documentation stated clearly that `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` should be used for statically allocated mutexes, and to get a mutex at runtime you should be using `pthread_mutex_init`. Whether this "hack" actually performs correctly or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh and to clarify things a bit, this answer was made _before_ the OP updated the question, it is a response to the question above the **Update** line.

Comment: Ah. I looked at what was below the Update line. Above the update line, there is only one mutex. If that is what the author wants, then, yeah, it does work. On the other hand, if the author wants a unique mutex for each call to `GetFastNativeMutex()` then the code will not work. Period. Besides, this is premature optimization. The cost of initializing a mutex is very, very small.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetFastNativeMutex` is in no way a factory function. It always returns the copy of the same mutex, the point of factory is to abstract allocation and creation of a new object, not to reuse the same one all the time. So no, this is not valid for any usage that wouldn't be done by using the same mutex as a global variable.

A quote from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html):

> The result of referring to copies of
>   mutex in calls to
>   pthread_mutex_lock(),
>   pthread_mutex_trylock(),
>   pthread_mutex_unlock(), and
>   pthread_mutex_destroy() is undefined

Comment: No it doesn't, those are different mutex's with equal values

Comment: @mathepic: Where does it say that a copy of a mutex creates a distinct mutex? I'm not convinced that copying mutex creates a new one, in fact I'm quite sure that in Windows, it is not true. Can you point me to the relevant documentation?

Comment: @mathepic - actually in another comment a link has been provide to the spec that shows that you're wrong: "The result of referring to copies of mutex in calls to pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_mutex_trylock(), pthread_mutex_unlock(), and pthread_mutex_destroy() is undefined." - here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html. Please remove the downvote.

Comment: I'm referring to the C semantics of copying, ie, that you get different data located in a different location. And FYI I did not downvote. Nobody did, in fact.

Answer (score -1):

It "works" if all myMutex instances should share the same POSIX mutex. You currently have one mutex and not one per MyClass object. This is most certainly not what you want, isn't?

Comment: The function returns a copy of the mutex.

Comment: You have luck: On linux are are right (I looked it up in the source). When you copy a pthread_mutex_t , you get a "clone" with the same state. However, this behavior may not portable. It has not be the case on all POSIX platforms. Imagine an implementation where pthread_mutex_t only contains a handle with a kind of mutex id. Just as an example, it will not work with pthread_t on Linux.